# Implementation of last_insert_id

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best way to get the last inserted id from a particular table? I see at least four different approaches:

```
1. SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
2. mysql_insert_id()
3. SELECT max(id) FROM table
4. SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

First approach beats the second one, because the second one returns 0 if id has `bigint` type. But the problem is - I can't be sure that the `id` I get - is from the table that I want, because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last `id` across the whole database. The third and fourth approaches are not so fast on large tables, but the fourth approach seems to beat the third one in terms of speed. What I want to know - is how you, guys, implement this task in real world projects.

Comment: `because LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the last id across the whole database` - but per connection.

Comment: Never use #3 or #4, because they won't handle any situation with concurrent users.... real world projects should never use these methods unless they want to be bug-ridden real world projects with corrupted data

Comment: 3+4 are highly unreliable and dangerous. #2 is simply calling #1 internally anyways. So... #1 or #2, never #3 or #4

Comment: But is there any guarantee that you will get the id from the table you want?

Comment: @Jacobian - last_insert_id shouldn't be a case of getting the id that __you want__... it should be a case of getting a guaranteed unique id value (withing the scope of integer size) assigned when you insert a new record into a table, and that's what you get with #1 or #2, and being able to retrieve that value for subsequent use when creating child records

Comment: I'm splitting hairs admittedly but since #2 is using the deprecated `mysql_` library that should be replaced with either the `mysqli_` or `PDO` equivalent - in which case, as has been noted, #1 and #2 do the same thing basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems with 3 and 4, such as

- they don't handle concurrent users
- they cannot handle recycled ids or other kinds of skips in id sequence
- ids can also roll over, which is not handled by them

1 and 2 are close to the same thing. They are both connection specific and as such should handle concurrent users just fine, and be context-aware so that you'd get what you expect.

If you feel that mysql_insert_id has some drawbacks on the data type it supports, you can use the first one instead. It should have about identical behaviour.